# Detect Firebase Realtime Change For Specific User

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using firebase realtime database. I have a bunch of users in my ref

```
let usersRef = db.ref('/users/);
```

Then I want to detect any changes here with

```
   usersRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {}
```

This will detect the change but will return all the users, not just the one that has changed a value.

How can I retrieve only the one that has changed in the database?

Thank you and im sorry if it's an amateur question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The listener receives a snapshot that contains the data at the specified location in the database at the time of the event. You can retrieve the data in the snapshot with the val() method.

That technically means any change in users node will return the whole node.

Are you trying to listen to a specific user's node? Then try changing your ref to:

```
let usersRef = db.ref('/users/userUID')
```

In case you are showing a list of all users and want to listen for updates for each of them, then you would have to add a new listener for each of them with the above reference. (Just change the UID)

Comment: For example if we have 50 users, and one of them were to change the first name, I would like to detect that change for that specific user. Is attaching a listener to all of them be reasonable? What if there are 10000 users? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2752798 I would NOT load all user at once tbh... you can show let's say 500 at once or so... for limits you can checkout the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits 10000 should not be an issue...

Comment: Please forgive me for not fully understanding.

So in a case where I have a db like:

users:
[{
 userID:1,
firstName:Bob
},
{userID:2,
firstName:John
]

And 1000's more of users..
How would I detect the change of only 47th user for example who changed his firstname? Just somehow attach a ref to all the users?

Comment: @user2752798 you need a separate listener for each user . With your current code you'll end up retrieving whole users node. That being said you need to know users uids I.e. the children keys in users node. Also what you've shared seems to be an array. Please share a screenshot of your realtime db instead

Comment: Thank you for your responses! Another quick question would be:

I am retrieving the data everytime a new user is online and storing it in a useState. My whole problem was that the useState was not being updated when the user would change a name while he or she is online.

Would it be easier or more efficient to just override the useState again everytime an update is detected in the users database in general? Rather than attaching listeners?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: @user2752798 you need listeners to detect the change.  They are the ones who notify client about update and using that you update the local state. Although I don't know best practices of React and also its different than original question so it maybe ideal to ask a different question for that.

Comment: Thank you! The upvote button is not allowed since I don't enough rep points. But I clicked the tick icon!